# AWS SQS Exception "413 Request Entity Too Large"

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, laravel-excel, laravel-vapor

I have been stuck for a while to figure out about the below exception any help would be apricated.
we are using AWS Lambda service on a Laravel project. and we are exporting a large number of data to CSV files using [Laravel Excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.0/exports/queued.html) and we are doing this through Laravel SQS queues.

php version: 7.2 
Laravel Framework: 7.30.1 
Laravel Excel : 3.1

Exception:

```
Aws\Sqs\Exception\SqsException /tmp/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php...
stage.ERROR: Error executing "SendMessage" on "https://sqs.eu-central- 
1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sqs.eu- 
central-1.amazonaws.com/` resulted in a `413 Request Entity Too Large` 
response:
HTTP content length exceeded 1662976 bytes.
Unable to parse error information from response - Error parsing XML: String could not be parsed as 
XML {"exception":"[object] (Aws\\Sqs\\Exception\\SqsException(code: 0): Error executing      
\"SendMessage\" on \"https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"; AWS 
HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/` resulted in a `413 Request Entity Too Large` response:
HTTP content length exceeded 1662976 bytes.
Unable to parse error information from response - Error parsing XML: String could not be parsed as 
XML at /tmp/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php:195)
[stacktrace]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/quotas-messages.html):

> **Message size**
> The minimum message size is 1 byte (1 character). The maximum is 262,144 bytes (256 KB).

My guess is that the files you're trying to send are larger than `256KB`, which is a hard limit for SQS messages in AWS.

The output `HTTP content length exceeded 1662976 bytes` suggests my guess might be correct.

The common pattern in this case is to upload the files to S3 and send a reference to the object through the Queue.

Comment: Yes file could be large that's why we are processing in SQS queues. So what you suggest in that situation?

Comment: I'm going to quote myself :) `The common pattern in this case is to upload the files to S3 and send a reference to the object through the Queue.` Upload the data to S3 and send bucket name + object key in the queue.

Comment: First part of your answer is correct. uploading file to s3 and from the queue send a reference to object. we came across with a custom solution I am going to post in answer so that it can help others.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when running csv imports on laravel vapor with the Laravel Excel library.  I was able to fix it without rewriting the file processing.

The simple solution for me was to change `implements ShouldQueue, WithChunkReading` to `implements ShouldQueueWithoutChain, WithChunkReading` on my importable class.

e.g.

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Imports;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldQueueWithoutChain;
    
    class BaseDataImporter implements ShouldQueueWithoutChain, WithChunkReading {
    ...
```

Here's whats going on under the hood: When Laravel Excel sees "WithChunkReading" it serializes all the chunks as a single "chained" job.  If your csv file has enough rows, the length of this chain can exceed 256kb. Using `ShouldQueueWithoutChain` changes this logic to create a small, easily queueable job for each chunk.

This error is hard to catch if you are testing locally with a database queue driver. Laravel Jobs can be something like 4GB. You can approximate this limitation by adding a migration to change your `jobs.payload` column from LONGTEXT to TEXT.  This will set the job size limit to 64KB, which is well below the SQS limit, but will be an effective canary for catching chained jobs that have way too many chunks for AWS ( assuming you don't anticipate needing to queue extremely large jobs ).

Comment: Never knew that, will give it a try in next deployment.

Comment: One tradeoff of running jobs without chaining is that if one chunk fails, the rest of the chunks will still run. This might not be what you want, depending on data needs.

Answer (score 2):

**Scenario** 
From the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/quotas-messages.html) hard limit to send data to SQS queue is `256KB`. that was happening because I was sending Collection object to the SQS Queue, and each object had  Multiple [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) Relationships so the object size became too large.

**AWS Solution**
Passing ids in array of collection object to SQS Queues helped to solve `Entity Too Large` problem.

**Excel solution**
Instead of using [Laravel Excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.0/exports/queued.html) I am using [Laravel Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#prepending-appending-to-files) append method to add rows to my csv file. I have tested with 50k rows and it works very well. Do not process all rows at once you may get yourself into AWS `timeout` exception, which is `15 minutes` per queue I believe.